# SWT ComboBoxCellEditor editable

Tags: java, swt, jface

I have a [TableViewer](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseJFaceTable/article.html) where the values in one column should typically come from a dynamic list.
I'm currently using [org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ComboBoxCellEditor](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jface/viewers/ComboBoxViewerCellEditor.html) , which is actually a Select-List: it stores the index of the selected value. If I change the underlying list (calling `setItems(String[])`, it's clumsy to keep the previous selected value... (specially if it's not included in the list anymore!) What I'd wish is actually a cell editor that stores, not the index from the list, but the string (perhaps letting the user edit it freely, perhaps not), where the list is just used as a suggestion at input time - like a "[combobox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combo_box)" was supposed to work in the good old days... Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to have your CellEditor to mimic the behavior that you are looking for. Extend `ComboBoxViewerCellEditor` and override `doGetValue()` method. Add modify listener on Combo control and also filter (which filters list items based on input text) to comboviewer.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at :

- [org.eclipse.wst.xml.ui.internal.properties.StringComboBoxCellEditor](http://org.eclipse.wst.xml.ui.internal.properties.StringComboBoxCellEditor) This class comes from WTP project; It's an extended ComboBoxCellEditor that selects and returns Strings.
- [codemirror.eclipse.ui.xquery.viewers.StringComboBoxCellEditor](https://github.com/angelozerr/CodeMirror-Eclipse/blob/master/mode/xquery/codemirror.eclipse.ui.xquery/src/codemirror/eclipse/ui/xquery/viewers/StringComboBoxCellEditor.java) It's the copy/paste of WTP StringComboBoxCellEditor; it adds the capability to add the item in the combo when it is not found.